# Matrix and Model design in Django

Tags: django-models, matrix

I have a matrix like this:

```
                0                 1                 2

    AX <= 1     standard          Bronze            Gold
    AX <= 2     Gold              Standard          Bronze
```

I want to write model for this matix. Is there any specific way for such data?

Is below model a right model for above matrix?

```
class Matrix(models.Model):
      ax = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=u"ax", default=None, null=True, blank=True)
      index = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=u"index", default=None, null=True, blank=True)
      metal = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u"Metal", default=None, null=True, blank=True)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you tell us what does that matrix represents? Cause it's difficult to say if you are wrong or not. What does "0 1 2" from the first row (columns headers) means? And Ax <= 1? You can see a database (SQL based database) as a group of tables, so the table you put here must have a django model (database table) that represents it as it is... But is difficult to say if we don't understand what you are trying to do...